# Почему у некоторых ЯП много компиляторов?

Tags: компилятор, интерпретатор

Почему у некоторых языков программирования несколько компиляторов и/или интерпретаторов? В чем разница между языком и его реализацией? 
Всегда ли "один язык - одна реализация" хорошо? Объясните, в чем смысл использования разных реализаций для разных задач?

Comment: Думаю потому-же, почему и много производителей машин. Или потому-что много, к примеру, стран. появляется технология, каждый начинает затачивать "под себя". Кто-то добавляет что-то от себя. Какой-то компилятор оптимизирует участки памяти. Какой-то лучше собирает программу для работы на распределенных системах. Итог один - машинный-код. А множество компиляторов зависит скорее всего от "популярности" языка

Comment: @Chubatiy, можете написать это в ответе?

Comment: Конечно, минуту

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеет в виду под "много". Вот например GCC для Windows, Linux и ARM - это разные компиляторы или один и тот же?

Comment: @AnT, Это один и тот же компилятор. Я имею ввиду несколько разных компиляторов под одну платформу (например выпускаемых разными компаниями) к примеру GCC, Borland C++ или MinGW.

Comment: На самом деле **у каждого компилятора свой язык**. Просто может случиться, что у нескольких компиляторов языки имеют большое количество общих черт. Эти общие черты могут быть описаны, например, в стандарте. Например, стандарте С++. Компиляторы, языки которых имеют все черты С++ являются компиляторами С++. Хотя в их языках обычно есть различия, они за рамками стандарта С++: не определённое/специфицированное стандартом или нарушения. И эти детали могут открывать другие, нестандартные возможности, или давать программам особые характеристики (малый размер, совм-ть с другой архитектурой, и т. д.).

Comment: Если отвязаться от С++, то может получиться очень интересный вопрос о грани между языком и его реализацией, которая и правда является источником большого числа недоразумений.

Comment: @D-side Не могли бы вы править вопрос? Я не могу корректно сформулировать.

Comment: А вы попробуйте. Вы ничего толком не теряете.

Comment: @D-side, не могли бы вы написать это в ответе? Пожалуйста.

Comment: Когда/если вопрос переоткроют. Пните меня, когда/если это случится :) Свой голос я оставил.

Comment: @Denis  люди добрые, я переформулировал вопрос как смог, переоткройте его пожалуйста!

Comment: @Vlad-from-Moscow

Answer (score 3):

Думаю потому-же, почему и много производителей машин.

Или потому-что много, к примеру, стран.

Появляется технология, каждый начинает затачивать "под себя".

Кто-то добавляет что-то от себя.

Какой-то компилятор оптимизирует участки памяти. Какой-то лучше собирает программу для работы на распределенных системах.

**Итог один** - машинный-код.

А множество компиляторов зависит скорее всего от "популярности" языка

Comment: Для ряда языков, существуют патентные ограничения не позволяющие никому кроме владельца создать собственный компилятор.

Comment: "**Итог один - машинный-код.**" не, необязательно. Точнее даже сказать, машинный код это платформозависимое понятие, поэтому то, что итог действительно *один*, утверждать сложно. На платформе "веб-браузер", к примеру, машинным кодом можно считать код на JavaScript, и clang+emscripten компилируют C++ в JS. Такие вот дела.